# Error when deploying django web application with daphne: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-channels, daphne

I have been battling with an error that I encountered when trying to deploy a django application that uses channels.

**Error in heroku logs**

```
Starting process with command `daphne friendship.asgi:application --port 52589 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2`
2021-06-02T19:51:57.338171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-02T19:51:57.105387+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-02T19:51:57.105477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.105796+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
2021-06-02T19:51:57.105861+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 170, in entrypoint
2021-06-02T19:51:57.106200+00:00 app[web.1]: cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
2021-06-02T19:51:57.106259+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 232, in run
2021-06-02T19:51:57.106713+00:00 app[web.1]: application = import_by_path(args.application)
2021-06-02T19:51:57.106774+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
2021-06-02T19:51:57.107059+00:00 app[web.1]: target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
2021-06-02T19:51:57.107118+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-06-02T19:51:57.107436+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-06-02T19:51:57.107491+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-06-02T19:51:57.107783+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-06-02T19:51:57.107986+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-06-02T19:51:57.108196+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-06-02T19:51:57.108533+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
2021-06-02T19:51:57.108768+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-06-02T19:51:57.108967+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./friendship/asgi.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.109233+00:00 app[web.1]: import errands.routing
2021-06-02T19:51:57.109290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./errands/routing.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.110045+00:00 app[web.1]: from . import consumers
2021-06-02T19:51:57.110094+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./errands/consumers.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.110331+00:00 app[web.1]: from .models import RoomMessage, PrivateChatRoom
2021-06-02T19:51:57.110378+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./errands/models.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.110708+00:00 app[web.1]: from accounts.models import CustomUser
2021-06-02T19:51:57.110756+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./accounts/models.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.111794+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
2021-06-02T19:51:57.111866+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
2021-06-02T19:51:57.112224+00:00 app[web.1]: class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
2021-06-02T19:51:57.112320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
2021-06-02T19:51:57.112739+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
2021-06-02T19:51:57.112789+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
2021-06-02T19:51:57.113140+00:00 app[web.1]: self.check_apps_ready()
2021-06-02T19:51:57.113193+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
2021-06-02T19:51:57.113463+00:00 app[web.1]: settings.INSTALLED_APPS
2021-06-02T19:51:57.113518+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
2021-06-02T19:51:57.113802+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2021-06-02T19:51:57.113852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
2021-06-02T19:51:57.114115+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImproperlyConfigured(
2021-06-02T19:51:57.114363+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import errands.routing
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'friendship.settings')
django.setup()

application = get_default_application()
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'friendship.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import errands.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            errands.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dotenv

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

dotenv.load_dotenv()


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG")

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'friendshipweb.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'errands',
    'channels',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'friendship.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'friendship.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'friendship.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [(os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'), 6379)]
        }
    }
}


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

**Procfile**

```
web: daphne friendship.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channels --settings=friendship.settings -v2
```

I have tried already to set the environment variable in heroku, changing asgi structure, trying different procfile configurations, but nothing seems to work. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem and for me the fix was that I imported some files that needed django to be initialized before setting the variable and initializing django.

Looking at your stacktrace, your problem is probably the same. When importing `errands.routing`, django needs to be already setup. Change your `asgi.py` to the following and see if it works:

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'friendship.settings')
django.setup()

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import errands.routing
from channels.routing import get_default_application


application = get_default_application()
```

Comment: life saver mate, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one with the stock authentication tie-in to Django:

```
import os

import django
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack  # new import
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'jobs.settings')
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  'http': asgi_app,
  'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(  # new
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),  # new
})
```

### *Notice the ordering!*

Notice someone somewhere else says that you have to initialize asgi_app before importing chat.routing (or something like that).